# How to construct a packet containing following hexa values

Tags: iphone

I need to construct packet containing following hexa  information

```
     01 05 00 03 D0 90 01
```

I need to send this data to tcp server
I am confused that how can i create one packet of this data so that i can sent to server device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crate a NSData

```
char a[7] = {0x01,0x05,0x00,0x03,0xD0,0x90,0x01} ;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:a length:7];
```

get bytes from NSData (this is in a **educational context!** of course it makes no sense to convert them back... but maybe you once need the oposite)

```
const void *test = malloc(7);
test = [data bytes];
```

You then should look at `NSURLConnection` and `NSMutableURLRequest` (or third party product [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)) for posting data to your server.

Comment: [clientSocket writeData:data withTimeout:-1.0 tag:1];

Comment: okay.. then you just pass the data (NSData instance) to your socket. Okay?

Comment: I don't understand the point of creating the NSData object is you're just going to turn around and convert the data back to a bytes string.